# list available network interfaces of a remote host (without SSH)?

Tags: networking

Is it possible to find the available network interfaces of a remote host (eth0, etc..) without being able to SSH to the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without access to the machine you can't list out it's interfaces, no.  If you know something about the interfaces (like their MAC address and what subnet they're on and if you're on the same subnet) you can do something like `nmap -sP x.x.x.x/m` where x.x.x.x/m is the subnet definition in CIDR format. That will do a ping sweep of the whole subnet and you can look for the MAC address in question.  Other than that there's not much you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need SSH specifically, but you do need a way to execute commands remotely and receive their output (e.g. telnet for the old-school). Looking at it from the remote end, there's no way to tell what hardware is plugged into the machine (which is basically what the question reduces to).